# Android: Download Image

Tags: android, imagedownload

I'm working on one project which is going very well, but I'm stuck at one point where I'm trying to download some Images...
Following method I used in my code to download Images..

```
public Bitmap DownloadImage(String STRURL) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;       
    try {
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(STRURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))             
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();  
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }                    
        }catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting"); 
        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
        }catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap; 
    }
```

This method working fine with my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 but not with Samsung Galaxy s7562..
I'm not getting whats the problem really is,,
Is that a memory problem?? Please help to sort out it..

Comment: What problem you are facing in your s7562 phone ? Post the stack trace.

Comment: Are you using `AsyncTask` for performing the download process or are you doing it in the main thread itself?

Comment: @MjZac I'm calling this method in AsyncTask..

Comment: Added permission for Internet?

Comment: @SpringBreaker It get stuck after calling this method..and the Alert comes like Application not responding force to close..

Comment: Without appropriate logcat or code, we can't tell you the reason for the crash.

Comment: @SpringBreaker I set log at each line in this method but at `response = httpConn.getResponseCode();` it get stuck..Without any error..